# Como obtener los tweets de una fecha especifica con tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

quisiera por favor que me indicaran como puedo sacar los tweets de hace 7 dias con tweepy, estaba intentandolo de esta manera, ir filtrando dia por dia pero el find siempre me retorna -1 con todos los parametros que ingreso, pienso que de pronto el since_id no es lo que necesito, agradeceria su ayuda

```
lista_tweet = []
lista_fecha = []
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="@Bancolombia",since_id="2020-05-18",tweet_mode="extended").items(1000):
    if tweet._json["created_at"].find("Tue May 21")>=0:
        print(tweet._json["created_at"])
        lista_tweet.append(tweet._json["full_text"])
        lista_fecha.append(tweet._json["created_at"])
```

Answer (score 2):

En principio tu código es correcto, pero para definir la fecha de búsqueda debes usar `since` en vez de `since_id`. Puedes revisar un ejemplo similar al que planteas en [este enlace](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-to-apis/twitter-data-in-python/).

```
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd

consumer_key= 'yourkeyhere'
consumer_secret= 'yourkeyhere'
access_token= 'yourkeyhere'
access_token_secret= 'yourkeyhere'

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words = "@Bancolombia"
date_since = "2020-05-18"

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              lang="es", #opcional
              since=date_since).items(5)
tweets
```

Si aún así recibes -1, es posible que no se hayan publicado tweets con tus criterios de búsqueda y fechas.

Comment: Hola @Sebastian, se resolvió tu problema con esta respuesta?. si es así, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

soy un novato y no consigo hacer rodar esto. me sale el siguiente error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Equipo2\Desktop\prueba\give_me_tweets.py", line 17, in 
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/386781)